# elementIsNotVisible throwing noSuchElementError in Selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium, automated-tests

I wrote a test to ensure a slideout panel closes in my selenium tests using node js. Whenever I close the panel I use the condition `elementIsNotVisible`. However an error is thrown, `noSuchElementError`. This error is technically correct because the element should no longer be on the page, but shouldn't `elementIsNotVisible` be correct as well?

Test.js file:

```
await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(testPage.addAllAnnotationsButton(driver)), 20000);
await testPage.exitGeneAnnotationsButton(driver).click();
await driver.wait(until.elementIsNotVisible(testPage.addAllAnnotationsButton(driver)), 20000);
```

Page.js file:

```
const testPage = {
      addAllAnnotationsButton: driver => driver.findElement(By.css(testPage.addAllAnnotationsButtonSELECTOR))
}
```

Error message(Note- Error message is thrown on the line where elementIsNotVisible is called):

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.slideout.opened:nth-child(6) button.ui.button.medium:nth-child(2)"}
```

Edit 1: Please note, I have tried using `stalenessOf` and I still receive the same error.

Comment: My question is how come elementIsNotVisible is throwing an error on an element that is not visible?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that when you close the panel, you use the condition **elementIsNotVisible** :

Here once you have closed the panel , the respective web element is not present in **DOM**. That is the reason you are getting **NoSuchElement exception**.

**Suggestion** : Use **invisiblityofElement** instead of **elementIsNotVisible**.

Though there are many reasons behind `NoSuchElement` Exception, one of the most common is try to interact with element/elements present in **frame/iframe** without switching the focus of web driver.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. This page I'm testing does not contain iframes.

Comment: Did you try with invisibilityofelement ? If so , are you getting the same exception ? As I have mentioned in my answer frame/iframes could cause NoSuchElement but  not necessarily.